# Sul significato di "dare corda"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Lessico famigliare* di Natalia Ginzburg ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Gino era serio, studioso, tranquillo; non picchiava nessuno dei suoi fratelli; andava bene in montagna. Era il prediletto di mio padre. Di lui, mio padre non diceva mai che era «un asino»; diceva però che «dava poco spago». Il **dar corda**, in casa nostra, si chiamava «dar spago». Gino, infatti, dava poco spago, perché leggeva sempre; e quando gli si parlava, rispondeva a monosillabi, senza alzare la testa dal libro. Se Alberto e Mario si picchiavano, non si muoveva e continuava a leggere; e mia madre doveva chiamarlo e scuoterlo, che venisse a dividerli. Leggendo, mangiava pane, adagio adagio, una pagnotta dopo l’altra; ne mangiava piú o meno un chilo, dopo il pranzo. 
>       – Gino! – gridava mio padre, – non dài spago! non racconti niente! e poi non mangiare tanto pane, farai l’indigestione!

Ho trovato il significato della locuzione "dare corda" sul [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/dare-corda):

> mostrarsi disponibile, incoraggiare: se gli dai corda non la finisce più di parlare

Anche sul [dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/corda.shtml) si legge questa definizione, che mi sembra abbastanza diversa da quella del De Mauro:

> **dare corda (pop)** 
> Fig.: dare a qualcuno ampia libertà di dire o agire, convinti che le sue azioni gli si ritorceranno contro. Fare in modo che chi vuole danneggiarci o sta per commettere un'azione riprovevole si spinga abbastanza avanti da compromettersi e tradirsi. 
> Il detto si ricollega alle esecuzioni capitali di un tempo, nella fattispecie al capestro, e dice integralmente: “dare abbastanza corda per impiccarsi”.

Comunque, dal contesto del brano citato, ho l'impressione che "dare corda" possa avere delle sfumature non presenti nelle definizioni di questi due dizionari.

Forse qualcosa come far vedere a una persona che ha trovato un ascoltatore con cui si può sentire a suo agio per parlare? È così?

Comment: Ah, curioso, a me risulta più familiare “dare spago” (cf. anche [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spago1)).

Comment: È un modo di dire molto comune, e il senso nel brano mi sembra sia quello riportato dal de Mauro, cioè mostrarsi disponibile.

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, ma mostrarsi disponibile a che cosa?

Comment: In senso generico, si può dar corda a qualcuno ascoltandolo, aiutandolo, consigliandolo o semplicemente prestando attenzione. Il riferimento è su chi “chiede corda” che generalmente insiste per avere quello che richiede.

Comment: Gino infatti “non dava corda” a chi gli parlava o alle richieste della madre.

Comment: @Hachi: Condivido. “Chiedere corda”, però, non l'ho mai sentito.

Comment: @DaG - neppure io, l’ho messo tra virgolette per meglio esprimere il concetto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dare corda" significa più o meno "incoraggiare qualcuno a continuare dandogli o dandole attenzione". Nel caso del testo che hai evidenziato, i genitori provano a parlare a Gino, ma lui legge e risponde solo a monosillabi, in questo senso non dà loro corda.

Spesso ha una connotazione negativa rispetto all'oggetto della frase, ad esempio:

> Se gli dai corda non finisce più di parlare.

Tradotto, "If you **encourage him**, he'll never stop talking", che si usa per dire "se lo incoraggi a continuare prestandogli attenzione, non finisce più di parlare" (perciò ignoralo, così smette). È comune dire "non dargli/darle corda" nel senso di "non incoraggiarlo/a", per esempio:

> Se i tuoi compagni di classe ti prendono in giro, non dar loro corda.

Che si può tradurre più o meno come "If your classmates mock you, **don't engage with them/ don't give them an excuse to keep doing it**".

Si può anche usare nel senso dato da Hoepli, anche se onestamente lo vedo più raramente. Il significato è lo stesso, ma la connotazione è leggermente diversa: si può "dare corda" a qualcuno volontariamente per indurlo o indurla a continuare a parlare, per esempio ecco una frase che potresti incontrare in un poliziesco:

> Se dopo un bicchiere o due comincia a parlare, dagli corda, potrebbe dire qualcosa di interessante.

Tradotto: "If he starts talking after a glass or two, **keep him going**, he might say something interesting". In questo caso "dare corda" significa, più o meno, "fingere interesse affinché qualcuno continui a parlare".

Infine, in quest'ultimo significato la "finzione di interesse" non deve avere per forza lo scopo di indurre chi parla a dire qualcosa di compromettente, può anche essere semplicemente per cortesia:

> Se il nonno comincia a parlare per l'ennesima volta del calcio, dagli corda, gli fa piacere parlare con qualcuno.

Tradotto: "If grandpa starts talking about soccer again, **humour him**, he likes having someone to talk to".

In questo senso si usa anche l'espressione "dammi corda!", ad esempio:

> Avanti, dammi corda!

che significa "so che non ti interessa quello che sto dicendo, ma almeno fai finta per un po'", potremmo tradurlo come "Come on, **humour me**!". Credo sia questo il significato nel testo che hai evidenziato:

> Gino - non dài spago!

significa "Gino - non fai nemmeno lo sforzo di parlare con noi!".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta! Quindi, se l'ho capita bene, se do corda a qualcuno, questo significa che presto attenzione a questa persona, ma non necessariamente nel senso di fargli o farle sapere che io sono un ascoltatore con cui si può sentire a suo agio per parlare, ma potrebbe essere anche in un altro senso: per esempio, fargli o farle sapere che do importanza a quello che fa. È così?

Comment: @Charo Grazie! Direi di sì, ma nella mia esperienza dell'uso comune della lingua "dare corda" ha quasi sempre una connotazione leggermente negativa, quindi più che "fargli o farle sapere che do importanza a quello che fa" direi "fargli o farle **pensare** che do importanza a quello che fa". Dire a qualcuno che gli stai dando corda in generale non è gentile.

Comment: Grazie del chiarimento, @user2723984. Forse spesso l'espressione ha questa connotazione  negativa, ma nel brano che ho riportato non sembra essere così: i suoi genitori si lamentano che Gino non dà loro spago.

Comment: @Charo È vero che questa connotazione è un po' più debole, ma è chiaro che Gino non è interessato a parlare con i suoi genitori, e il padre dicendo "Gino, non dai spago!" potrebbe intendere che Gino dovrebbe perlomeno sforzarsi di fare conversazione, anche se non ne ha voglia. Questo è l'ultimo significato nella mia risposta, potremmo renderlo come "Gino, at least humour us!". Ho aggiunto un altro esempio del genere.

Comment: Hai ragione, @user2723984, ma qui quello che ha una connotazione negativa è "non dare spago", cioè, "non dare corda" (e non "dare corda": se Gino dessi corda sarebbe considerato positivo dai suoi genitori).

Answer (score 1):

Che io sappia, le espressioni "dare corda" (assecondare qualcuno) e "tirare (troppo) la corda" (abusare della pazienza o disponibilità di qualcuno) derivano entrambe dal mondo contadino, con riferimento agli animali legati:

- più dai corda, nel senso di allungare la corda a cui è legato, più l'animale ha libertà di movimento (quindi stai assecondando la volontà dell'animale)
- più l'animale tira la corda a cui è legato, più il contadino fatica a trattenerlo (quindi l'animale sta abusando della libertà di movimento che gli è concessa... almeno dal punto di vista del contadino)

Per quanto riguarda l'interpretazione data dal dizionario Hoepli di "dare abbastanza corda per impiccarsi" potrebbe sì fare riferimento alle esecuzioni ma potrebbe anche far sempre riferimento al mondo contadino: nuovamente, l'animale alla corda, lasciato libero di muoversi senza freni, prima o poi finirebbe con l'aggrovigliarsi/impiccarsi da solo se la corda fosse abbastanza lunga.

L'espressione è anche usata nel suo senso letterale di "allungare il tratto di corda a disposizione di chi vi è legato", nell'ambito dell'alpinismo.